# How to instantiate the properties of a constructor of a class in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, hive

I want to instantaite the properties of a class while trying to create a object of it in flutter

DataBaseProvider File

```
class DatabaseProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Box<Contacts> _contactsBox = Hive.box<Contacts>('contacts');

  Contacts _selectedContact = Contacts();

  Box<Contacts> get contactsBox => _contactsBox;

  Contacts get selectedContact => _selectedContact;

  ///* Updating the current selected index for that contact to pass to read from hive
  void updateSelectedIndex(int index) {
    _selectedIndex = index;
    updateSelectedContact();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ///* Updating the current selected contact from hive
  void updateSelectedContact() {
    _selectedContact = readFromHive();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ///* reading the current selected contact from hive
  Contacts readFromHive() {
    Contacts getContact = _contactsBox.getAt(_selectedIndex);

    return getContact;
  }

  void deleteFromHive(){
    _contactsBox.deleteAt(_selectedIndex);
  }
}
```

Model File

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Contacts {
  @HiveField(0)
  String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  String imageURL;
  
  @HiveField(2)
  String? number;
  
  Contacts({
    required this.name,
    required this.imageURL,
    this.number,
  });
}
```

Now whenever i try creating a object of Contacts Class it aks for the reuqired properties values.
For Ex:
Contacts ct = Contacts( name: name, imageURL:imageURL)

So in the DatabaseProvider file how shall i initialize these above properties(name and imageURL as it is required) so that I am able to create a object of the class Contacts

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide some default parameters inside the model file -

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Contacts {
  @HiveField(0)
  String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  String imageURL;
  
  @HiveField(2)
  String? number;
  
  Contacts({
    required this.name = "some name",
    required this.imageURL = "URL",
    this.number = "425890",
  });
}
```